# Are there any in-memory OLTP features available in SQL Server 2022 but not SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, memory-optimized-tables, sql-server-2022, feature-comparison

I know that in-memory OLTP has a lot of new features in SQL Server 2016, but I have heard nothing since then. Are there any in-memory OLTP features available in SQL Server 2022 but not SQL Server 2019?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16#performance

Comment: From https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask : "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"